# ImageResizer - Save Image as a Larger Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, imageresizer

I am trying to use the .net [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/generate-versions) to save an image to a specified size. I am unable to save a smaller image to larger dimensions with the current code I am using. For example, I upload an image that is 200x200, the _thumb version will be saved as 100x100 but the _medium and _large versions will still be 200x200.

How can I save the uploaded image to the specified larger images? Such as versions.Add("_extraLarge", "width=2000&height=2000&crop=auto&format=jpg"); or versions.Add("_XXL", "width=auto&height=3000&crop=auto&format=jpg");

```
//GenerateVersions(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
Dictionary<string, string> versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//Define the versions to generate
versions.Add("_thumb", "width=100&height=100&crop=auto&format=jpg"); //Crop to square thumbnail
versions.Add("_medium", "maxwidth=400&maxheight=400&format=jpg"); //Fit inside 400x400 area, jpeg
versions.Add("_large", "maxwidth=1900&maxheight=1900&format=jpg"); //Fit inside 1900x1200 area

//Loop through each uploaded file
foreach (string fileKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
    if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue; //Skip unused file controls.

    //Get the physical path for the uploads folder and make sure it exists
    string uploadFolder = MapPath("~/uploadsAIM");
    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

    //Generate each version
    foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
    {
        ////Generate a filename (GUIDs are best).
        //string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + suffix);
        string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, file.FileName + suffix);

        //Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
        //fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, fileName, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true); //deprecated fileName
        fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file, fileName, new Instructions(versions[suffix]), false, true)).FinalPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: resizing a low resolution image to a higher resolution doesn't make it high quality. instead it will blur out the image.

Comment: True. What can I use that does fractal interpolation or something to adjust for the enlarged images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the scaling mode is set to `DownscaleOnly`.  Set the [`Scale`](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_instructions.html#a1cbc099613881686c6a2ec98380842a3) on the instructions to either [`up` or `both`](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/doxygen/namespace_image_resizer.html#aca52f6f1e90c78a5e5e79c6d709a571c) depending on your need.

Just note that upscaling an image tends to create blurry images.